# Cannot resolve setFallback in Uber SDK

Tags: uber-api

SetFallback method is not working, I am using UBER SDK

```
implementation 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
```

Here is the sample code

```
   RequestDeeplink deeplink = new RequestDeeplink.Builder(mContext)
                            .setSessionConfiguration(config)
                            .setFallback(Deeplink.Fallback.MOBILE_WEB)//this line is showing error(Cannot resolve setFallback)
                            .setRideParameters(rideParams)
                            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved myself my replacing the

```
implementation 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
```

By

```
implementation ("com.uber.sdk:uber-rides:0.8.0") {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    implementation project(':uber-core-android')
    implementation project(':uber-rides-android')
```

[Here are the core and rides SDK links](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk)